# How to use ojdbc.policy for Oracle connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am using Spring batch multi threaded program to connect to oracle database. Could you please let us know how to use ojdbc.policy means -D argument to the program or where to keep this file?

Answer (score 1):

The policy file could be used like

```
java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=ojdbc.policy YourApp
```

For more information you might have a look into the tutorial from Oracle [about policy files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour2/step4.html).

In your case you should amend the JVM parameters used to start your Spring batch application.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate how to " amend the JVM parameters used to start your Spring batch application". Is it something Spring specific?

Comment: @Debopam As I said this depends how your Spring Batch application is started. If it's a standalone app then like mentioned in the answer `java -Djava.security.manager=...` if your app is running inside an application server you need to amend the JVM arguments for the application server startup. Without any further information from your side how your application is started nobody can tell. Add this information to your question.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks for the clarification.